# How can I get Streamlit to display years in data frames without a comma?

Tags: python, dataframe, streamlit

I am creating a Streamlit app for a final project for school. It contains two raw data frames and two graphs. However, when I post the data frames to the app, the Year columns come out with commas, i.e. 1,993 instead of 1993.

So far, I've tried saving the cleaned data with the Year columns set as int and also as objects--didn't work. I've also tried saving the cleaned data as a .csv to load into my Streamlit code instead of a .xlsx, in case there was something funky with the Excel format that caused the commas to appear--this also didn't work. I expected for the data frames to be posted to the Streamlit app in a YYYY format as opposed to a Y,YYY format, but I got the Y,YYY format instead. In the end, I used matplotlib to post the graphs since it doesn't add unnecessary commas.

This is what my streamlit code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st

st.title('Global Biodiversity Decline')

st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')

live=pd.read_excel('living-planet-spread.xlsx')

live=live.drop(axis=1, columns='Unnamed: 0')

live['Year']=live['Year'].astype('object')

live2=pd.pivot_table(live, index='Year', columns='Region', values='Average Index', fill_value=0)

st.subheader('Decline of Average Index by Year')

if st.checkbox('Show Raw Biodiversity Data'):
    st.subheader('Raw Data')
    st.write(live2)
    st.caption("Data Source: World Wildlife Fund (WWF) and Zoological Society of London")

chart=pd.DataFrame(live2, columns=['Africa', 'Asia and Pacific', 'Europe and Central Asia', 'Latin America and the Carribean', 'North America', 'World'])

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(chart)
ax.set(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Index (%)')
ax.legend(['Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'South America', 'North America'])
st.pyplot(fig)

st.caption('Above is a graph plotting the average index of biodiversity per region. Note that all regions are on a steady decline, particularly Latin America which has a sharper decline than all other regions. One possible cause of this could be deforestation related to farming. See the below graph.')

st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')

#I had to set the index as 'Year' in order for the x-axis of this graph to show up as the Years instead of a numbered index
land=pd.read_excel('fao_land_data_spread.xlsx')
land=land.set_index('Year')

st.subheader('Regional Increase in Land Use for Farming by Year')

if st.checkbox('Show Raw Land Area Data'):
    st.subheader('Raw Data')
    st.write(land)
    st.caption('Data Source: UNData')

chart2=pd.DataFrame(land, columns=['Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'South America', 'North America'])
chart3=pd.DataFrame(land, columns=['World'])

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(chart2)
ax.set(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Area (1000 Ha)e+06')
ax.legend(['Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'South America', 'North America'])
st.pyplot(fig)

st.caption('Above is a graph plotting the area of farmland used per region...')

st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')

st.subheader('Global Increase in Land Use for Farming by Year')

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(chart3)
ax.set(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Area (1000 Ha)e+06')
st.pyplot(fig)

st.caption('I put the Global area of farmland in its own graph...')
```

And this is a sample of what each data frame looks like:

```
    Africa  Asia    Europe  North America   South America   World
Year                        
1961    927526.222222   911930.555556   825966.444444   586216.444444   502466.333333   4.146173e+06
1962    927657.000000   913559.333333   826292.888889   585067.666667   503954.444444   4.149369e+06
1963    928080.888889   914962.222222   825754.111111   584786.000000   505403.444444   4.152637e+06
1964    928313.333333   916675.333333   825170.777778   584079.000000   506533.333333   4.155457e+06
1965    928717.111111   918125.555556   825569.555556   583276.444444   507664.888889   4.159057e+06
```

```
Region   Year   Average Index   Upper Index Lower Index
44  Africa  2014    32.492869   68.628636   15.238575
45  Africa  2015    31.293573   66.256152   14.669147
46  Africa  2016    32.054221   68.026893   14.968882
47  Africa  2017    34.445875   73.433580   15.991854
48  Africa  2018    34.445875   73.433580   15.991854
```

Comment: Hi katerade!  1. Can you add a minimal and reproducible example by removing any extra line of code that does not bring anything? 2. Can you add a picture of what you are getting on your browser? That would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description and code snippet, it seems the comma is caused by the `Year` column being read in as a numeric type from Excel. The comma seems to be introduced when converting the `numeric type` to an `object type` which seems to be a default behavior of Pandas excel reader.

You can try specifying the data type of `Year` as a String then convert it back to numeric or int as such:

```
live=pd.read_excel('living-planet-spread.xlsx', dtype={'Year': str})

# Convert the "Year" column to a numeric 
live['Year'] = pd.to_numeric(live['Year'])

# Convert the "Year" column to an integer
live['Year'] = live['Year'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Converting to string to a numeric to an integer didn't work, but only converting to a string did! Since I just needed `Year` to show up properly on the graph, this was good enough for me. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it's working!